# use of unresolved identifier 'SCNScene'

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit

I am trying to create a SceneKit game but I am unable to use any of the SceneKit tools. I have tried a few things:

1. import SceneKit
2. Reinstall Xcode
3. Search Documentation
4. Link Binary with Library
5. Google

Comment: Using the import module where?

Comment: http://prnt.sc/ehlz0y
http://prnt.sc/ehlz8q

Comment: Try cleaning it first with `cmd + k` then build it without running with `cmd + b` then run it with `cmd + r`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did your project/product used the name `SceneKit`? Try to create a project with a different name.

Comment: It worked! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to import SceneKit at the top of your source code.

```
import SceneKit
```

This is different from importing the framework into your target. From your screenshot it looks like you've added the library but it's not clear whether you have added the `import` to your source code.

Do you see the error at compile time, or build time?